# How do I set the texture sampler state in XNA for BasicEffect?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, textures, effect

According to microsoft the BasicEffect.Texture uses the TextureFilter state and if it's not set it uses TextureFilter.Linear.

Where can I set the TextureFilter state for BasicEffect?

Is it possible to set a clamp/wrap method for texture sampling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Got rid of my last answer.  I knew that I had written it a cleaner way before.

Try:

`GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;`

[SamplerState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.samplerstate_members.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.XNA.FRAMEWORK.GRAPHICS.SAMPLERSTATE%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) members can be found here.

Comment: I tried that but I get an assert saying '{"Cannot change read-only SamplerState. State objects become read-only the first time they are bound to a GraphicsDevice. To change property values, create a new SamplerState instance."}'

Comment: That's also giving me the same read only error. I tried making it equal SamplerState.LinearWrap but it quit saying 'A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'

Comment: *edit: I just found out it doesn't work for wrap of any ckind, but it's fine when I set it to PointClamp or LinearClamp. I'd like to wrapping to work...

Answer (score 3):

This can also be specified in [`SpriteBatch.Begin()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.begin.aspx).
e.g.:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone);
```

See a discussion on this at: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/63537.aspx